# how to run bash file in win-bash

Tags: bash, win-bash

I am unfortunately having to use windows in work, and so I have installed win-bash to have a unix shell running. all going well but I am having an issue running the following .sh file:

```
bash $ ./qf.sh

.\qf.sh: option not available on this NT BASH release
.\qf.sh: fork: Bad file descriptor
```

qf.sh is:

```
#!/bin/bash

cat test.csv | while read line
do
        echo "${line//,/ }"  | xargs ./adder      
done
```

I find it hard to believe someone would create a bash emulator incapable of running a bash file. curious that the error message writes .\qf as opposed to ./qf

Can anyone shed some light on this?

Comment: pick a mature product. mingw, cygwin?

Comment: just tried cygwin - much better.

Answer (score 1):

use `MinGW` or `Cygwin`

MinGW: http://sourceforge.net/projects/mingw/files/?source=navbar

Cygwin: http://www.cygwin.com/

Answer (score 0):

Using Cygwin absolutely killed this error for me. I do wonder however, how this should work with MinGW. I don't see any unix command executable directory to include in the path (like cygwin64\bin with Cygwin)